# Which expressions should I choose to say “thanks for your help”?

Tags: translation, expressions

If I want to say "Thanks for your help", which sentence is correct and which one is more commonly used?

> 1. 谢谢你的帮忙
> 2. 谢谢你的帮助

It seems that the first one is more uncommon but I'm not really sure.

Comment: I think both are correct and can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, 帮忙 and 帮助 are different.

> 帮忙: [verb]to help some do something .This word itself has declared its object[忙] already. I think the phrase "do sb a favor" is a more appropriate equivalent in English.
>
> 帮助: [verb]to help. [noun]help. This word needs an object

You would say,

> 你可以来帮忙吗？ Could you come and help?
>
> 你可以帮助**我**一下吗？Could you help me?
>
> 我帮不上忙。 I am not able to help.
>
> 我无法帮助**你**。(Actually, 我帮不了你 is more common) I am not able to help.

Imagine that you are going to prepare a meal in your house,to entertain your friends, but you have a lot of work(buying, washing, cutting, cooking...) to do
, so you ask me for help. You would say,

> Huang,明早你可以来帮忙吗？Could you please come and help(do me a favor) tomorrow morning?  By using 帮忙, you should not express its object, and that doesn't matter, because in the context, I understand what I can help you. I say,
>
> 没问题。我能帮助你什么呢？=没问题，我能帮什么忙呢？No problem! What can I help you?
>
> 你可以帮助我去超市买菜。 You can help me buy the foods in the supermarket. Here, you won't say 帮忙, because you have to express the object explicitly.

Now, for your question, I think the 2nd sentence is more common, though the first one could be understood. I guess you would not say "Thanks for your doing me a favor" in English, would you?

You can also say other words to express this meaning,

> 谢谢(or 谢了 if you are familiar with the interlocutor)
>   辛苦你了
>   辛苦了
>   麻烦你了
>   麻烦了

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 4):

They are the same and both uncommon. More common way is just 谢谢 or 辛苦了.

Answer (score 2):

I think both uses are correct, depending on the context. The former might be more appropriate for work and labor (as in you *help* someone do something), while the latter might be more appropriate for support and assistance (as in you *aid* someone in doing something).

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you want to thank someone for helping you by supporting you somehow, you could use

```
谢谢你的支持
```

but it is rather formal.